# Pass variable to string in include file - PHP

Tags: php, string, variables, include

What I am trying to do is to have an include file with generalized language in a string that will be used across multiple pages, but I also need to pass a variable to the string from the current page.

Here is an example:

Here is a snippet of the index.php page:

```
<?PHP
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/prefix.php');

echo $GENERAL_STRINGS['user_not_found'];
?>
```

Here is the include page:

```
<?PHP
$GENERAL_STRINGS['user_not_found'] = 'User account not found<br /><a href="/register/?email='.$email.'">Register Today for FREE</a>';
?>
```

The $email variable is always empty when the link is referenced, I assume this is because it is looking for the $email variable from the include page instead of the index page.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [printf()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) or [sprintf()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
<?php
$GENERAL_STRINGS['user_not_found'] = 'User account not found<br /><a href="/register/?email=%s">Register Today for FREE</a>';
?>
```

Use it in this way:

```
<?php
printf($GENERAL_STRINGS['user_not_found'], urlencode($email));
?>
```

Comment: I think you mean `urlencode` since the `$email` variable is going into a url.?  But otherwise, +1

Comment: Changed it.
@Alexander, it is. $email is not defined in the language file, but in index.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it. All good. May be, you forgot assigning of $email.

```
<?PHP
$email = 'emal@email.com';
$GENERAL_STRINGS['user_not_found'] = 'User account not found<br /><a href="/register/?email='.$email.'">Register Today for FREE</a>';
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing things up. There is a separate language file which should not refer to variables in index.
The language file is included before assigning values in index.

Comment: Lol. $email not in index. 4email in inclufing file.

Comment: It's reffering to $email in the included file, but it shouldn't do that.