# Echoing a string of data from within an include

Tags: php, string, include, echo

I want to echo a string of page specific text.  I don't have a problem with this when the  tag is on the page but, I am having issues when it is placd within an include.  Example:

index.php

```
<?php

$StringData1 = "String of page specific text on page echoes.";
include("IncludeHeader.php");

?>
<html>

<head></head>
<body>

<p>Start Echo Test</p>
<p>Echo Test For StringData1:  <?php echo "$StringData1"; ?></p>
<p><?php include("IncludeFile.php");?></p>
<p>Stop Echo Test</p>

</body>
</html>
```

IncludeHeader.php

```
// Many Global Variables called from various CSV Files.  To be exact $StrindData2 is actually $StringData2[1] from an array.  The array is of a row of CSV fields
$StringData2 = "String of page specific text in include won't echo.";
```

IncludeFile.php

```
Echo Test For Included StringData2:  <?php echo "$StringData2"; ?>
```

When index.php is run the output is:

```
<html>

<head></head>
<body>

<p>Start Echo Test</p>
<p>Echo Test For StringData1:  String of page specific text on page echoes.</p>
<p>Echo Test For Included StringData2:  </p>
<p>Stop Echo Test</p>

</body>
</html>
```

From this example, how can I get $StringData2 to echo from within the include?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As an aside: you do not need to quote variables! `echo $StringData2` works fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558336/pass-variable-to-string-in-include-file-php

Comment: Also, activate error reporting and let us know if you see any errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: Just a raw copy and paste of your code, into its respective files, and everything works fine for me. I get both outputs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  In an attempt to abbreviate I messed up the question.  Editted to be more accurate now

Comment: Edited my test to conform to your new version, and everything still works fine here. There must be something else.

Answer (score 2):

The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) states:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

Also that:

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function. So, it will follow the variable
>   scope of that function. An exception to this rule are magic constants
>   which are evaluated by the parser before the include occurs.

Was your example abbreviated or is that your exact code?  Your original example as shown should work fine.

Your updated example should still work.

Scratch my last edit. I think you really need to come up with an abbreviated example that reproduces the same behavior.

Comment: The example was abbreviated.  Actually the $StringData2 is $StringData[1] pulled from an array.  The array is built from a row csv fields (long story, but can't use SQL).  It is contained within another include to be used (and editted) globally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**IncludeFile.php**

```
  Echo "Test for Included StringData2:  $StringData2";
```